# Construct GADT while parsing json

Tags: haskell, text-parsing, aeson, gadt

I have a data structure that I have created with GADT and I want to parse some json to this GADT using `aeson`. But the type checker complains that It's only possible to create one of the constructors of the GADT in all the cases. See this example:

```
data Foo = Hello | World

data SFoo :: Foo -> Type where
  SHello :: SFoo 'Hello 
  SWorld :: SFoo 'World

instance FromJSON (SFoo a) where
  parseJSON = withText "Foo" \case
    "hello" -> pure SHello
    "world" -> pure SWorld
```

So I want to be able to parse the "hello" string to `SHello` and the "world" string to `SWorld`. The type checker complains with the following error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘'World’ with ‘'Hello’
  Expected type: Parser (SFoo 'Hello)
    Actual type: Parser (SFoo 'World)
• In the expression: pure SWorld
  In a case alternative: "world" -> pure SWorld
  In the second argument of ‘withText’, namely
    ‘\case
       "hello" -> pure SHello
       "world" -> pure SWorld’
```

How can I parse some json to a GADT structure like this?

Comment: You're trying to have the parsing function return different types depending on the input. This cannot happen, a function must have a single return type. You have to pack both variants into the same type and return that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
instance FromJSON (SFoo a) where
```

doesn't fly. You'd get

```
parseJSON :: forall a. Value -> Parser (SFoo a)
```

which means that the caller gets to choose which `a` they want, and `parseJSON` is not in control of parsing the `a` from the JSON. Instead, you want

```
data SomeFoo = forall a. SomeFoo (SFoo a)
instance FromJSON SomeFoo where
    parseJSON = withText "Foo" \case
        "hello" -> pure $ SomeFoo SHello
        "world" -> pure $ SomeFoo SWorld
        _ -> fail "not a Foo" -- aeson note: without this you get crashes!
```

where now

```
fromJSON :: Value -> Result SomeFoo
```

does *not* tell you which branch of `SFoo` it will be returning in its type. `SomeFoo` is now a pair of a `a :: Foo` type and a `SFoo a` value. `fromJSON` is now in charge of parsing the entire pair, so it controls both the returned type and the value. When you use it and match on the `SomeFoo`, *that* will tell you which type you have to deal with:

```
example :: Value -> IO ()
example x = case fromJSON x of
    Error _ -> return ()
    Success (SomeFoo x) -> -- know x :: SFoo a where a is a type extracted from the match; don't know anything about a yet
        case x of
            SHello -> {- now know a ~ Hello -} return ()
            SWorld -> {- now know a ~ World -} return ()
```

Note that `SomeFoo` is basically isomorphic to `Foo`. You may as well write

```
instance FromJSON Foo where ..
```

and then

```
someFoo :: Foo -> SomeFoo
someFoo Hello = SomeFoo SHello
someFoo World = SomeFoo SWorld
instance FromJSON SomeFoo where parseJSON = fmap someFoo . parseJSON
```

Note that you *can* write the following two instances:

```
instance FromJSON (SFoo Hello) where
    parseJSON = withText "SFoo Hello" \case
        "hello" -> pure SHello
        _ -> fail "not an SFoo Hello"
instance FromJSON (SFoo World) where
    parseJSON = withText "SFoo World" \case
        "world" -> pure SWorld
        _ -> fail "not an SFoo World"
```

...but they're not particularly useful, except as another way to write `FromJSON SomeFoo`:

```
instance FromJSON SomeFoo where
    parseJSON x = prependFailure "SomeFoo: " $
        SomeFoo @Hello <$> parseJSON x <|> SomeFoo @World <$> parseJSON x
```

Comment: The latter pattern is very common when using GADTs with runtime input: first parse to an untyped ADT representation, then “typecheck” it to produce the typed GADT packaged up as an existential or [sigma](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.6/docs/Data-Singletons-Sigma.html#t:Sigma) type.